# Store cv::Mat in Swift variable

Tags: c++, ios, swift, opencv

I have a c++ opencv function that gets the gray scale of an image and stores it into an array.

```
+(cv::Mat) makeGray:(UIImage *) image {
    // Transform UIImage to cv::Mat
    cv::Mat imageMat;
    UIImageToMat(image, imageMat);

    //Transform image to grayscale
    cv::Mat grayMat;
    cv::cvtColor(imageMat, grayMat, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    return grayMat;
}
```

Whenever I try storing this in a variable using swift

swift function:

```
@IBAction func convertImage(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let grayMat = OpenCVWrapper.makeGray(photoImageView.image)
}
```

The entire program just freezes without throwing out an error.

The swift function works great when I return an UIImage:

```
+(UIImage *) makeGray:(UIImage *) image {
    // Transform UIImage to cv::Mat
    cv::Mat imageMat;
    UIImageToMat(image, imageMat);

    //Transform image to grayscale
    cv::Mat grayMat;
    cv::cvtColor(imageMat, grayMat, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    return MatToUIImage(grayMat);
}
```

But I'm looking to return a 3darray and not an Image.

Comment: C++ classes cannot be imported into Swift. How have you made `makeGray` available in Swift ? Maybe you have done it in a wrong way.

Comment: Edited question lemme know if it helps

Comment: Your added portion does not make sense as Swift can import `UIImage`.

Comment: Is there some way to allow Swift to import a `cv:Mat` ?

Comment: NO. Create a wrapper method which returns the type Swift can import. You may have tried some trick in the bridging header, that does not make Swift import C++ classes.

Comment: makes sense, thanks!